# can't load an array to ngTable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I tried to write a small and simple ngTable demo, but got a problem:

When I try to put an array to ngTable, the browser shows only the head line of the table, but not data. the result is in screenshot:

[image]

All the code are in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/snsYWG?p=preview)

Here is the "data":

```js
  var books = [
  {
   "name": "Html from start to give up",
   "price": 2,
   "comment": "An awesome book to be a pillow",
   "available": true
  },
  {
   "name": "AngularJS from start to give up",
   "price": 2,
   "comment": "Too hard to be a pillow",
   "available": false
  }];
```

and here is the way i created a ngTable

```js
vm.bookTable     = createTable(books);
  
var initpageSize = Number(localStorage.getItem('page_size') || 20);
  vm.pageSize      = initpageSize;
  vm.pageSizes     = [10,20,30,50,100];
  
  function createTable(data){
    var initParams = {
      sorting: {name: "asc"},
      count: vm.pageSize
    };
    var initSettings = {
      counts: [],
      paginationMaxBlocks: 13,
      paginationMinBlocks: 2,
      dataset: data
    };
    return new NgTableParams(initParams, initSettings);
    
  }
```

and here is part of the html:

```html
<body ng-controller="myController as vm">
    <div>
      <table ng-table= "vm.bookTable" 
            class = "table" 
            show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
        <td title = "'name'" filter="{name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
         {{row.name}} 
        </td>
        <td title = "'price'" filter="{price: 'number'}" sortable="'price'">
         {{row.price}}
        </td>
        <td title = "'comment'" filter="{comment: 'number'}" sortable="'comment'">
         {{row.count}}
        </td>
          
        </tr>
        
      </table>
      
    </div>
    
    
    <p>Hello {{vm.name}}!</p>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is you call `createTable` function before you set `initpageSize` 
so `initParams.counts` is undefined

You have to put this lines before you call to `createTable`

```
  var initpageSize = Number(localStorage.getItem('page_size') || 20);
  vm.pageSize      = initpageSize;
  vm.pageSizes     = [10,20,30,50,100];
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jfpfg1uwTEge7F4KufvX?p=preview) you have a working plunker.

Comment: it works now! Thanks~
and here is my final version, fix a bug in html file to show the "comment"